# Multiplying Values in a Form

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a form that requires an input from the user, and multiplies this input by the value in a cell from a different worksheet. For some reason, when I run the code the value comes out as 0. Is there anything wrong with my code?

---

```
Sub PartOrder()

Dim qty As Variant




qty = Application.InputBox("How many assemblies are needed?")

Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
PartOrderForm.Show



End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CompleteForm_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Part Number"
ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = "Part Name"
ActiveSheet.Range("C1") = "Number of Parts Needed"

ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B7")
ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C7")
ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F7") * qty




Else: End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, post the code itself (edit your question) so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: You are not passing the variable qty to the other sub and therefore the second sub sees `qty` as a new variable and it is `0`

Comment: Once you get that resolved, you will want to double check that the user entered a numeric value in the InputBox or you are just going to get errors when they enter something like `X` instead of a number.

Comment: My apologies for incorrect formatting, I made the edits. Thank you for the replies! I changed the qty variable to a global variable and it's now working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of your form module (it should be at the top of *every* module, actually) would have given you a compile error giving you a hint for what's going on: the `qty` variable is not in scope in the form module (hence the "variable not declared" compile error with `Option Explicit`), so you're multiplying by a `Variant/Empty` value that equates to `0`.

Find a way to get `qty` (or a copy of it) in-scope in the form module - either by promoting it to module-level (and making it `Public`), or otherwise passing it as a parameter to the form - perhaps using a property, like so:

```
Option Explicit '<<<<< should be in EVERY module
Private localQty As Double

Public Property Get Qty() As Double
    Qty = localQty
End Property

Public Property Let Qty(ByVal Value As Double)
    localQty = Value
End Property

' now use either Qty or localQty for the multiplication
```

The calling code only needs to pass the value before showing the form:

```
Qty = Application.InputBox("How many assemblies are needed?")

If IsNumeric(Qty) Then
    With New PartOrderForm
        .Qty = Qty
        .Show
    End With
End If
```